# How to get a specific element from a list using Selenium with Python

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, mining

Example of a list:

```
<div class="c-article-metrics-bar__wrapper u-clear-both">
      <ul class="c-article-metrics-bar u-list-inline">
         <li class="c-article-metrics-bar__item">
            <p class="c-article-metrics-bar__count">"277k "
              <span class="c-article-metrics-bar__label">Accesses</span>
            </p>
         </li> 
         <li class="c-article-metrics-bar__item">
            <p class="c-article-metrics-bar__count">"6 "
              <span class="c-article-metrics-bar__label">Citations</span>
            </p>
         </li>
         <li class="c-article-metrics-bar__item">
            <p class="c-article-metrics-bar__count">"594 "
              <span class="c-article-metrics-bar__label">Altmetric</span>
            </p>
         </li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

I am trying to get count of "Citations" from the list. The problem is, if there are no citations, the list element will be omitted.

My idea was to get info from p and span tags and save data in two lists. Then iterate through the span tag list, and if the "Citations" string is found, return text at that index from p tag list, like this:

```
metrics_labels = self.wd.find_element_by_css_selector('span.c-article-metrics-bar__label')
labels = [label.text for label in metrics_labels]

metrics_counts = self.wd.find_element_by_css_selector('p.c-article-metrics-bar__count')
counts = [count.text for count in metrics_counts]

for i in range(len(labels) - 1):
  if labels[i] == "Citations":
    return counts[i]
```

But it doesn't work, what I am missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like instead of collecting all elements with `find_elements` you are only collecting 1 by using `find_element` here:

```
metrics_labels = self.wd.find_element_by_css_selector('span.c-article-metrics-bar__label')
```

and here:

```
metrics_counts = self.wd.find_element_by_css_selector('p.c-article-metrics-bar__count')
```

To fix it, try using `find_elements_by_css_selector`:

```
metrics_labels = self.wd.find_elements_by_css_selector('span.c-article-metrics-bar__label')
labels = [label.text for label in metrics_labels]

metrics_counts = self.wd.find_elements_by_css_selector('p.c-article-metrics-bar__count')
counts = [count.text for count in metrics_counts]
```

I hope this works, good luck! If it doesn't help, please let us know the error you are getting.